# Mvc Razor normal rendering strange characters

Tags: html, model-view-controller, character

I have a simple razor view which seems to be rendering the - character with funny characters.

There are no javascript or dynamic string generating involved. It is simple html that states the following as an example:

Please note online check-in is available

However, when viewing it on the browser it shows as follows:

"Please note online checkâ€in is available"

This does not happen when debugging locally, only once published on the server.

Example html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 ociTxt">
        Please note online check‐in is available
    </div>
</div>
```

the class "ociTxt" is the following:

```
.ociTxt {
color: red;
font-size: 13px;
margin-top: 15px;
```

}

This is what the browser shows:

screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Please assist or provide me with possible causes such as locale etc. if it could have an effect.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character between *k* and *i* isn't an ordinary hyphen (ascii 0x2D, a character Unicode calls *Hyphen-Minus*).

The character is actually Unicode codepoint U+2010, which Unicode calls *Hyphen*.

You should be able to display it in html using `&#8208;`. Whether every browser will render it properly is another matter.

Or simply edit it out and use the normal ascii character instead.

This is how I reached my diagnosis. I cut this line

```
Please note online check‐in is available
```

out of the example html in your question, and pasted it into a Python 3.5 console, like this:

```
>>> a="Please note online check‐in is available"
>>> a
'Please note online check‐in is available'
```

Then I checked to see if the entire line was ascii:

```
>>> a.encode("utf-8")
b'Please note online check\xe2\x80\x90in is available'
```

It wasn't. So I established the position of the character in question by finding out where `k` is:

```
>>> a.index("k")
23
```

And then I retrieved the codepoint of character 24.

```
>>> a[24]
'‐'
>>> ord(a[24])
8208
```

The other thing that is noticeable is that the two hyphens don't look the same. I'm afraid I have to show you this as a screenshot because the difference isn't visible with the fonts SO uses. The first line is pasted from your question, the second is after I replaced the offending character with an ascii hyphen.

[image: Screenshot from PythonAnywhere console showing different hyphens.]

As to how it was working up to two weeks ago, or why it is only this particular hyphen and not the others: that is not a question you should be asking me. Look in your source control system for the answer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the feedback, however there are multiple other places the hyphen is used on the page. The other question is also, this was working fine till about two weeks ago? If the above is the reason, would it not have been like this since the beginning?

Comment: @MaximusIVI I've edited the answer, adding a demonstration of correctness.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much. This put me in the correct direction. I just noticed something very strange. Once the solution is published to the server it is automatically putting in these strange characters. I changed from Web deploy to File system. Not sure why the server is doing this though. I edited the file on the server and took the funny blocks out and just put a hyphen in and now it is working.

Comment: It looks like a conscious decision somewhere along the line to substitute typographic hyphens for Unicode *Hyphen-Minus*. If this were a book, that would be entirely the right decision. A typographic hyphen is shorter, thicker and closer to the baseline than the ascii dual-use character. And a proper minus sign (Unicode U+2212, *Minus Sign*) is wider, to match the crossbar of the `+` sign. If policy requires typographic hyphens, then care just needs to be taken to convert *Hyphen-Minus* to the corresponding html entity `&#8208;` instead of passing illegal utf-8 encodings through.